# SQL How to match 2 tables using between values in the same column

Tags: sql, range, between

I'm struggling selecting records from table A that are between values in the same column in table B. See the basic structure of these tables here:

Table A

```
Id   Depth           Comment         
1    150            Status is good
2    215            Status is good
3    330            Status is bad
```

Table B

```
    Id   Depth          Material        
    1    130            Hard
    2    200            Soft
    3    220            Very Hard
    4    280            Very Hard
    5    350            Soft
```

So, what I am trying to do is to select all the values from Table A that are higher than the depths in Table B, but lower than the next value (within the range between values in the same column).Depth and display Comments & Material. The results I'm expecting are:

```
    Depth  Comment          Material         
    150    Status is good   Hard
    215    Status is good   Soft
    330    Status is bad    Very Hard
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: Are the IDS related between the tables? And which tables depth do you want displayed in the output?

Comment: Hi, all the data is in an Oracle database, but I've got them linked in a MS Access 2013 and, in the future, it will be a MySQL.

Both tables have 2 common ID's (ID1 and ID2) but the depths don't necessary match from one table to the other. The depths I'm interested are located in Table A, but I want to retrieve values from Table B, when Table A.depth is within a range in Table B.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery for this.  The exact syntax depends on the database, but they are all simple.  Here is ANSI standard syntax:

```
select a.*,
       (select material
        from b
        where a.depth >= b.depth
        order by b.depth desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as material
from a;
```

Depending on the database, the `fetch first 1 row only` might be `limit 1` or it might be `select top 1` or it might be something else entirely.

EDIT:

In MySQL, you would do:

```
select a.*,
       (select material
        from b
        where a.depth >= b.depth
        order by b.depth desc
        limit 1
       ) as material
from a;
```

In MS Access:

```
select a.*,
       (select top 1 material
        from b
        where a.depth >= b.depth
        order by b.depth desc, b.id
       ) as material
from a;
```

In Oracle 12g the above works.  In other versions, it is slightly more complicated:

```
select a.*,
       (select distinct first_value(material) over (order by b.depth desc)
        from b
        where a.depth >= b.depth
       ) as material
from a;
```

Comment: @JaviGonzalez . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the IDs are related and the depth you want to see id the one from TableA

```
SELECT a.Depth, a.Comment, b.Material
FROM Tablea a
INNER JOIN Tableb b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.Depth > b.Depth
```

Comment: There are 2 ID's related among the tables, but depths are not necessary matching in both databases. There are thousands of depths in b that are higher than a, so I'm sorry to say this solution won't work, as I just want to locate a.depth in a range in b.

Answer (score 0):

The following will execute as is on Oracle. Comment out the "from dual" and change "Comment" to [Comment] and it will execute on SQL Server as well. It provides just the output you show. It may even execute in MySql, but you'd have to store the data in actual tables rather than use CTEs.

```
with
TableA( Id, Depth, "Comment" )as(
  select  1, 150, 'Status is good' from dual
  union all
  select  2, 215, 'Status is good' from dual
  union all
  select  3, 330, 'Status is bad' from dual
),
TableB( Id, Depth, Material )as(
  select  1,    130,            'Hard' from dual
  union all
  select  2,    200,            'Soft' from dual
  union all
  select  3,    220,            'Very Hard' from dual
  union all
  select  4,    280,            'Very Hard' from dual
  union all
  select  5,    350,            'Soft' from dual
)
select  a.Depth, a."Comment", b.Material
from  TableA  a
join  TableB  b
  on  b.Depth =(
        select  Max( Depth )
        from    TableB
        where   Depth <= a.Depth );
```

The trick is to join each row of TableB with the one row of TableB with the largest depth value that is less than or equal to the depth value of the row from TableA. Don't let the subquery throw you. Assuming Depth is indexed, this performs as well or better than just about any other method. But if TableB is as small as you have shown, it will all be read into cache anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue here is that there are thousands of depths in both tables and are not indexed, so this example won't be applicable as I need a method that evaluates not only the existing depths, but the future ones to come.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "future." If TableB is changed by adding new entries ("Durable", "Very Durable", etc.) or changing the existing thresholds, the query will still work fine. While I'm here, can you explain how the Depth value works? You start with a low value (Hard) then a larger value (Soft) then even higher values (Very Hard) to the highest value of all (Soft). So why is 349 Very Hard but 350 would be Soft?